# how to check if checkbox is checked in react styled components

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, styled-components, checked

I'm building a project with react styled components, And I need to check if checkbox is checked.
Now I'm doing it with react hook (usestate).
I would love to know if there is a built-in method that returns true or false

Comment: Not sure what you mean by built-in method. See if this example helps. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-feather-b3p3ov?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

The two ways of handling forms with React are described (and documentation linked) below:

### [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

In HTML, form elements such as , , and  typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with setState().

### [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

To write an uncontrolled component, instead of writing an event handler for every state update, you can use a ref to get form values from the DOM.

And also from the React documentation:

***If you’re looking for a complete solution including validation, keeping track of the visited fields, and handling form submission, Formik is one of the popular choices. However, it is built on the same principles of controlled components and managing state — so don’t neglect to learn them.***